# Connect C# GRPC client to Go Server

Tags: c#, go, grpc, grpc-go

I'm attempting to connect to a Go GRPC Server from a C# Client but the client channel is failing to connect to the server.

I would expect that there should be no issues in connecting to a GRPC server that is written and hosted by Go and a client written in C#.

---

My Go Server connection is setup thus:

```
lis, err := net.Listen("tcp", ":50051")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("Failed to listen: %v", err)
}

s := grpc.NewServer()

pb.Register**ServiceServer(s, &server{})
reflection.Register(s)
if err := s.Serve(lis); err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("Failed to serve: %v", err)
}
```

This is fairly standard and I know that my Server is working as I am able to connect with a Go client using the supplied port:

```
conn, err := grpc.Dial("localhost:50051", grpc.WithInsecure(), grpc.WithBlock())
```

---

But when I attempt to connect using a C# Client using the `Grpc.Net.Client` package as thus:

```
var channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress(@"http://localhost:50051", new GrpcChannelOptions
{
   Credentials = ChannelCredentials.Insecure
});
```

I get a `Grpc.Core.RpcException: 'Status(StatusCode=Internal, Detail="Bad gRPC response. Response protocol downgraded to HTTP/1.1.")'` exception.

Or by using the `Grpc.Core` package as thus:

```
var channel = new Channel("localhost:50051", ChannelCredentials.Insecure);
```

results in a `Grpc.Core.RpcException: 'Status(StatusCode=Unavailable, Detail="failed to connect to all addresses")'` exception.

I've tried both methods with and without `Http2UnencryptedSupport` set within the C# client but I've run out of ideas on why I am unable to connect.

Any suggestions on where I am going wrong would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you already tried combining the `Http2UnencryptedSupport` thing with setting the `Net.Client` manually on ForAddress? `Net.Client.DefaultRequestVersion` is HTTP1.1 by default. Maybe also try setting `Net.Client.DefaultVersionPolicy` to `HttpVersionPolicy.RequestVersionExact`.

Comment: Thanks @TylerKropp pushing me to look at this again. If I try using the latest Grpc NuGet packages (v2.34.0 at the moment) and setting both `AppContext.SetSwitch("System.Net.Http.SocketsHttpHandler.Http2Support", true);` and `AppContext.SetSwitch("System.Net.Http.SocketsHttpHandler.Http2UnencryptedSupport", true);` I am able to send a recieve message from the golang server. I'm not sure what has changed since v2.29 and v2.34 but one of the changes in here has resolved this for me.

Comment: OK, yeah the documentation did mention fixing it at a certain version: "must use Grpc.Net.Client version 2.32.0 or later". I guess it really was Microsoft's fault. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/troubleshoot?view=aspnetcore-5.0#call-insecure-grpc-services-with-net-core-client

Comment: Why are you using HTTP instead of HTTPS? gRPC uses HTTP/2 which in turn requires HTTPS.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos since I was using an unsecure channel for this test I therefore have to use a 'http' channel instead of 'https'. HTTP/2 support is still enabled via the `AppContext.SetSwitch` but with unencrypted support enabled for use without credentials (not recommended for a production environment).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For .NET 3.x, set:

```
AppContext.SetSwitch(
    "System.Net.Http.SocketsHttpHandler.Http2UnencryptedSupport", true);
```

and use `http` for the protocol in the URL.

For .NET 5.0, use version `Grpc.Net.Client` version 2.32.0 or later.

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/troubleshoot?view=aspnetcore-5.0#call-insecure-grpc-services-with-net-core-client