# Grpc as subproject

Tags: c#, server, client, grpc

I am trying to implement a scenario where the Grpc Client on the desktop  will listen to a remote Grpc Server on a different machine .

There is an already existing project which deals with the launching of the application.I wanted to add Grpc Client as a subproject or as an extension to the already existing  project which will listen to the remote server on the different machine and communicate using Grpc protocol.

Is it possible to add csproj or client project to use Grpc protocol to this already existing project which launches the client application?
I tried adding the Grpc client project,it doesnt give me the option to add csproj file or any reference except the executable file.
Any suggestion would be helpful here.

Comment: Yeah of course that is possible. You need to add a reference to the project containing the proto definitions and install the NuGet packages Grpc.Tools and Google.Protobuf to have access to the protoc compiler. I think you need to make your question more clear and explain exactly what is not working, so people can help you.

Comment: I wanted to ask is it possible to make a client under different solution interact with a server under different solution without making separate solutions for servers and clients.I am getitng below issue while trying to do this: Status(StatusCode="Internal", Detail="Bad gRPC response. Response protocol downgraded to HTTP/1.1.")
Press any key to exit...What can be the reasons for this?Any suggestions?

Comment: It is possible, you pretty much have to do what I wrote in the previous comment. Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62197286/connect-c-sharp-grpc-client-to-go-server) helps your error. If you don't post any code, people cannot help you much with such errors :)

Comment: var channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress("https://(ip adress here)", new GrpcChannelOptions { HttpHandler = httpHandler });
        new GrpcChannelOptions { HttpHandler = httpHandler });var client = new Greeter.GreeterClient(channel);
        var reply = await client.SayHelloAsync(
                          new HelloRequest { Name = "GreeterClient" });
        Console.WriteLine("Greeting: " + reply.Message);
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
        Console.ReadKey();

Comment: That's just looks like the default client-side code from the MS example for the GreeterService. I don't think anybody will be able to help you with the little information you give...